# Abstract wrapper for stl containers?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I'd want to expose some objects as abstract containers with stl-style manipulation possibilities (for_each loops, iterators) and hide container implementation details.

Performance issues don't matter (virtual calls and even memory allocation while copying "universal" iterator is acceptable).

I'm going to write an abstract container interface with pure virtual functions (+ "universal" iterator over the container)  and an implementaition adapter for stl sequential containers.

But maybe there are useful existing libraries for this purpose?

Or it's totally a bad idea?

Comment: What would be the benefit gained that you could not implement with underlying stl containers?  In C++0x the `auto` keyword can be used to imply the correct iterator type for a container by the _rvalue_ but that may not be enough for your needs.

Comment: why do you want to do that? STL containers are doing different tasks with different performance guarantee, if you don't mind performance you should not create a "universal container" but just use std::vector.

Comment: @AJG85 ,@Alessandro Teruzzi: I don't want to recompile "client" code when implementaion decides to change container (for instance) from vector to deque. Stl used here as well known standard for container manipulation, not for max performance

Comment: Your trying to write a PIMP container. Scott Myers has a discussion on this in one of his books. Even though the containers are very generic because of there underlying implementations they are not just cut/paste replaceable. ie. You can't replace a vector with a map without some extra work.

Comment: @user STL is actually known for performance as well. Perhaps you need a common interface between client and server implementation to decouple backend changes from the frontend client?

Comment: @AJG85 yes, I need a common interface. But I suppose that it is convinient for user to have an interface which may be used with common well known patterns or simple stl algorithms as for_each

Comment: @Martin: Seems your are rigth, there are problems to generalize all stl containers. However, I have less ambitios purpose to generalize at least sequential containers in mind(vector. klist, dequee) with simple iteration possibility

Comment: +1 for a question that has been bugging me for a long time. I want to have the power of Java style iterators too. I've wrapped Java design decision into classic C++ iterator using clone technique and pimpl idiom, but that seems ugly.

Comment: Just a little side note: once you got the iterators generalized, you can use simple ranges (like boost's iterator_range) to wrap you containers uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

[Thomas Becker has some useful advice (type erasure)](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).  You may also find [Stroustrup's SCARY paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/SCARY.pdf) useful.

Comment: +1 for mentioning type erasure and becker's work - any_iterator is probably the perfect solution here. No idea why you mention SCARY tho, I thought that was mostly about removing the allocator dependency from iterators (which has nothing to do with generic interfaces, but implementing the iterator on the same "level" as the container and not as a nested class iirc).

Comment: SCARY, of course, is an implementation detail and, as you said, it's orthogonal.  I added that sentence later when I realized it could potentially make implementing and experimenting with the new iterators a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If your "objects" aren't STL objects but custom ones, I think it's a good idea.

As you can see on http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html , vector "is a model of" RandomAccessContainer. Most Boost packages use similar concepts (the term realy is "concept")

In C++, you've got two possibilities to do this :

- An abstract class (interface) as you suggested
- Templates

With templates you can do something as :

```
doSomething < AnythingThatIsIterable >(AnythingThatIsIterable i){
    for (AnythingThatIsIterable::itertaor it = i.begin(); it != i.end(); ++i){
        it->foo()
    }
}
```

- Any class which provides an iterator, begin and end will work : std::vector, but also your own objects.
- These objects don't have to inherit from any interface, so std::vector *will* work.

Comment: my objects may be or may be not STL objects, I want to hide this fact at compile time for client's code to  provide freedom to change the implementaion container without forcing client code to recompile. So I'd like to get an abstract class (interface) which is a model of RandomAccessContainer and an implementation adapter for particular container (possible stl one) which implements such an interface

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](http://fakedetector.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fakedetector/fakebase/src/SinglePassIterator.h?view=markup) my forward iterator wrapper for Java style implemented one. It's ugly. Boost parts are optional an might be refactored out.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic solution to the problem of "exposing a C++ class in such a way that users of the class do not have to recompile their programs whenever my implementation of the class changes" is the pImpl pattern. For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Comment: C++ iterators are copyable. Pointers don't provide the semantic needed for this. Note also, that concrete type of iterator is unknown an in user code. This makes pure PIMPL inapplicable here.

Comment: You just have to 1. wrap your iterators in a similar fashion (yep, also using PIMPL), 2. implement your nontrivial copy operation (although it's rather trivial in its nontriviality).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the user's question completely.  He/She wants a custom container class that exposes to the user an STL-like interface.  The standard STL containers do not suffice in some manner and so they are not a suitable choice.

For example, I have an interface class for a 'Dataline' called IDataline.  An implementation of the IDataLine interface takes at construction a delimited string, parses it and exposes the list of fields. via a const_iterator with forward_iterator_tag semantics.
No STL container can do this out of the box.

Furthermore, my client class wants to be able to iterate through two data line fields and compare them, field by field.

I have defined the IDataline interface as follows:

```
 1 class IDataline
 2 {
 3 public:
 4    class const_iterator 
 5    {
 6      public: 
 7           virtual const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& rhs) =0;
 8           virtual bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) =0;
 9           virtual bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) =0;
10           virtual const_iterator& operator++() =0;
11           virtual const_iterator  operator++(int) =0;
12           virtual const Field& operator*() =0;
13           virtual const Field* operator->() =0;
14           virtual const Field& operator[](size_t idx) =0;
15           virtual size_t offset() =0;
16    }; 
17
18    virtual const_iterator begin() =0;
19    virtual const_iterator end() = 0;
20 };
```

The problem can be seen on lines 11, 18 and 19 - we need to be able to return a const_iterator, which requires a copy constructor, but since it is virtual, there is neither a default nor a copy constructor (for the interface type) and the compiler (properly) balks.

You might argue that I could define begin() and end() as:

```
virtual const_iterator& begin() = 0;
virtual const_iterator& end() = 0;
```

Then, I can create two instances of the specialized iterator in the specialized host and return references (or pointers for those who prefer those), to get this to work for my case.

The problem is that such an implementation does not meet all the requirements for forward iterators and will break in more general use cases that rely on forward iterator semantics.

There are two ways I've found after a bit of thought (and colleague consult) that this can be addressed:

1. Does your host class have to be **completely** abstract?  If you can minimize the abstraction to just the behavior you need to vary, then your instantiable host can embed a concrete iterator (because an instance of the class itself can be instantiated) and you have what you need.
2. **Eduardo Leon** above indicates that the iterator itself can be wrapped using the pimpl (Pointer to an implementation) idiom.  While there is a lot of material available that thoroughly describes that technique, **Basilev**, in comments below **Leon's** suggestion, indicates that he doesn't believe the pimpl idiom will work.  My colleague offered to me a technique to try, so I will work up a tested sample.  If it works, I'll share it.  If not, I'll detail the experience gained in the sample and wait for someone more knowledgeable to weigh in on whether or not pimpl is applicable in this case.